# IMEI Number In bb 10 Cascades

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I want to get the imei number In bb 10 cascades.In that path,   I need to to add

```
  using namespace bb::data;   
  #include <bb/device/HardwareInfo>
```

I have Also Included

```
     LIBS += -lbbpim
     LIBS += -lbbsystem
     LIBS += -lbbdevice
     LIBS += -lbbdata
```

files to my project.pro file !!!  but I am getting Error message like...

```
- expected namespace-name before ';' token

- 'data' is not a namespace-name
```

I want to know why i am getting this error ,how to resolve that Error and I would be hapy if post any code snippet how to get device Unique Id or IEMI Number in BB 10 Cascades !!!

Comment: and also 'hardwareInfo' was not declared in this scope  error: expected type-specifier before 'HardwareInfo'  error: expected ';' before 'HardwareInfo'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try remove your

```
using namespace bb::data;
```

and then try

```
QString deviceImei = bb::device::HardwareInfo().imei();
```

Comment: The real problem here is that you're trying to use your namespace (the ``using namespace`` line) before it's even declared (it's declared in the header you're including). Your code would have worked simply by swapping those two lines. However, ``using namespace`` is considered as a bad practice and should be avoided, @iamanyone's solution is better.